# iOS watchdog is killing my web app with native shell randomly

Tags: ios, cordova, web-applications

I am receiving feedback from my users upgraded to iOS 8 (8.0, 8.1) says that they are experiencing crashes, but I can't reproduce on my iPod touch and simulators. No crash report received from iTunes Connect either.

So I doubt that it is the watchdog that's killing my app.

Later I noticed the main script file takes nearly 200ms to load with Chrome on PC, and I guess this is the reason my app is been killed.

FYI, I am using eval to load this script file for some reason, and I am not using Cordova or PhoneGap but my own native shell (though I guess it doesn't matter).

Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: If Main Thread (UI Thread) is getting blocked for long time, then iOS itself kills the app. Suggestion, if possible move your time-taking tasks to background threading, and allow user to access some UI interaction.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have made some fundamental changes to the new version of this app that will take time-taking tasks background. Though for this version, during loading, those tasks have not started at all. It's just taking that long to eval the main script.

Comment: But are you allowing initial screen loaded, even though its having only an image?

Comment: Yup, I have splash images for native shell as well as for the web app. And the crash is happening when the splash image for web app being shown (which is GIF).